# How do I print only the last names on CodeHS 8.4.12: Librarian, Part 2?

Tags: python

This is what I'm supposed to do:
In the Librarian exercise, you asked the user for five last names, and you then printed a list of those names in sorted order.

In this exercise, you will ask the user for five full names. You should still print a list of last names in sorted order.

Each time you retrieve a name from the user, you should use the split method and the right index to extract just the last name. You can then add the last name to the list of last names that you will ultimately sort and print.

Here’s what an example run of your program might look like:

```
Name: Maya Angelou
Name: Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie
Name: Tobias Wolff
Name: Sherman Alexie
Name: Aziz Ansari
['Adichie', 'Alexie', 'Angelou', 'Ansari', 'Wolff']
```

This is my code right now:

```
name_1 = input("Name: ")
name_1.split()
name_2 = input("Name: ")
name_2.split()
name_3 = input("Name: ")
name_3.split()
name_4 = input("Name: ")
name_4.split()
name_5 = input("Name: ")
name_5.split()
my_list = [name_1[-1], name_2[-1], name_3[-1], name_4[-1], name_5[-1]]
my_list.sort()
print my_list
```

My code right now prints only the last letter, not the last word. How do I get my code to print the last word?

Comment: Have you tried any of this: "Each time you retrieve a name from the user, you should use the split method and the right index to extract just the last name"?

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Then you shouldn't be using `input()` in the first place. Better to upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python string manipulation", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: This is on CodeHS. I have no control over what version of Python CodeHS uses.

Comment: As for your immediate problem, you read in a string and put *specifically* the last letter into the list.  You chose not to use the assignment instructions.

Comment: I didn't even see that the instructions told me to do that until now. I just updated my code. However, the split method isn't doing anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is doing some_string[-1] on a string which takes only the last letter of that string. Solution is to use some_string.split() on your string to split it by space into a list of values and then take the last element of that list with some_list[-1].

```
names_list = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    names_list.append(input("Name: "))
sorted_last_names = sorted([name.split()[-1] for name in names_list])
print(sorted_last_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than the answer above. For me, it's more clear this way.

```
name_list = []
for i in range (5):
    input_name = input("Name: ")
    name_list.append(input_name.split()[-1])
   

name_list.sort()
print(name_list)
```